# trying to call a closure function in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a timer that I want to start by calling

`countdownTimer.start(600,'/page2.html');`

After showing the timer counting down from 600 seconds, it will redirect to page2.html

I also want to resume a previous timer (from a cookie) by calling the following. I'm just using cookies to save the value where it left off, so if the page is refreshed it will resume counting instead of starting over.

`countdownTimer.resume(123, '/page2.html');`

I'm getting all kinds of errors, about inner html not being defined (I assume this is related to the variables at the top of the function not being called).

can someone please help me understand how to create javascript objects like this? it has always confused me :/

```
var countdownTimer = (function() {

    var elem = document.getElementById("countdown");
    var url     = '';
    var end     = 60;
    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = 60000;
    var _hour   = 3600000;
    var timer;

    function pad (n, amount) {
        return n > parseInt(Array(amount).join("9")) ? "" + n : "0" + n;
    }

    function showRemaining () {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0 ) {
            clearInterval( timer );
            elem.innerHTML = "Offer Expired";
            window.location.href = url;
            return;
        }
        var minutes = Math.floor( (distance % _hour) / _minute );
        var seconds = Math.floor( (distance % _minute) / _second );
        var milliseconds = Math.floor( (distance % _second) );

        elem.innerHTML =  pad(minutes, 2) + ' <span>:</span> ';
        elem.innerHTML += pad(seconds, 2) + ' <span>:</span> ';
        elem.innerHTML += pad(milliseconds, 3);
    }

    var start = function (secondsToExpire, url) {
        url = url;
        end = new Date().getTime() + (secondsToExpire * 1000);
        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1);
    }

    var resume = function (customEnd, url) {
        url = url;
        end = customEnd;
        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1);
    }

    var currentTime = function () {
        return 500;
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        resume: resume,
        currentTime: currentTime
    };
})();
```

Comment: My guess is that it's complaining about `elem.innerHTML` being undefined. This probably means that `elem` is `null`, for some reason. Perhaps the code is being run before the DOM is ready? Or perhaps the element has a different `id`?

Comment: crap you are right... the rest of the function can be ran automatically except that one line